# Host phantomjs as cloud service

Tags: web-services, azure, cloud, phantomjs, azure-cloud-services

I m using phantom.js for simulating some steps and to generate few pdf/image. Now I'm trying to host as service so i can use it from any place.

Is there any way to host as service in azure cloud and use it across the glob.